# Secure authentification with django graphql jwt reactjs

Tags: reactjs, django, postgresql, graphql, jwt

I did a website using frontend reactjs and back django, using graphQL to communicate with DB.

I need to post data on a database (with a form accessible just when the user is logged in). For now I am able to connect it and get a token with jwt. but I did not succeed to post data on the database with graphQL with the token, and having a "unauthorized" page when token is not valid (unlogged).

Can please you guide me to a good tutorial which can help me how to do that? I am searching and I am non founding anything useful...

Thanks a lot in advance for your help !

Comment: test your workflow with Postman,, code later checking network requests (headers and body)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but do you know a tutorial for with this combination : postgres+django+jwt+graphql+reactjs ? I am a beginner, searched a lot and I did not found anything.

Comment: start with BE, test with Postman as it should work with any FE with JWT, make sure BE works properly, code FE later